# How to update the value of Date picker from input field, Angular 5 Angular Material 5

Tags: typescript, datepicker, angular-material, angular5

I have to input field, first input get the date from back end service
   and show the date to view, second input is the input of date picker,
   how can i make the the value of first input to update the value of
   second input of date picker.

> Ex: I get the date from back end service like 10/05/1995 its fine but
>   when i open the date picker  the value of date picker is today    date
>   not 10/05/1995.

How can i make the the value that i get from my service to update the date picker

```
<div class="mb-24" fxLayout="row">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="client.Birthday" formControlName="Birthday" placeholder="{{'Ditëlindja' | translate}}" required tabindex="3">
        <input matInput  [hidden]='true' [matDatepicker]="picker">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker  (selectedChanged)="updateDateToString($event)"></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

This is a picture of what happend
[I got like this, the two input are not the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BATk.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you need to update value of `picker` in controller. When you get the result from service you must be updating `client.Birthday`, at the same time you need to update `picker` as well.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date

Comment: the documentation of angular material don't help to my project @camden_kid

Comment: @PraveshKhatri i am new in angular, how can  update in the same time picker